# Do functions in R package raster and sp preserve cell number order?

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

I am working with functions in the R package `raster` and `sp` to calculate summary statistics for all the pixels in circles of various sizes. To save time when working with many rasters, I have precalculated the distance of every point in the raster from the center point using the `xyFromCell()` and `spDistsN1()` functions. That function returns a vector with length equal to the number of cells in the raster. In addition, I've converted the raster to a data frame with number of rows equal to the number of cells in the raster using the `as.data.frame()` function. Then, I can index the data frame by finding all rows with a distance less than or equal to the size of my circle, and calculate summary stats. I just wanted to check whether both those functions preserve the cell number order. See example code below. It appears to work but I would like someone to confirm this.

```
library(raster)

# Make fake raster
foo <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10)

rfoo <- raster(foo)

# Get coordinates of each cell
cfoo <- xyFromCell(rfoo, 1:ncell(rfoo))

# Distances from center point to the coordinate of each cell
distfoo <- spDistsN1(cfoo, c(0.5, 0.5))

# Radius of circle to extract
r <- 0.25

# Coerce raster to data frame
dffoo <- as.data.frame(rfoo)

# If correct, these values should be the cell values for all cells within 0.25 of the center point
dffoo[distfoo <= r, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code works well. I repeated your work but using a different package, `sf`, to conduct the same analysis. We got the same results.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
    
# Make fake raster
foo <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10)
rfoo <- raster(foo)
# Convert raster to a matrix with point information
rfoo_m <- rasterToPoints(rfoo)
# Convert to a data frame
rfoo_df <- as.data.frame(rfoo_m)
# Convert to sp object
rfoo_sf <- st_as_sf(rfoo_df, coords = c("x", "y"))
# Create a sp object as one point with coordinate 0.5, 0.5
target_sf <- st_point(c(0.5, 0.5))
# Calculate the distance, store the reuslt as a new column in rfoo_df
rfoo_df$dist <- st_distance(rfoo_sf, target_sf)
# Filter rfoo_df with dist <- 0.25
rfoo_df[rfoo_df$dist <= 0.25, "layer"]
[1] 34 44 54 64 35 45 55 65 36 46 56 66 37 47 57 67
```

#### Benchmarking

Here I compared the performance between OP's `spDistsN1` method and `st_distance` method from my post.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  m1 = {dist_col <- st_distance(rfoo_sf, target_sf)},
  m2 = {distfoo <- spDistsN1(cfoo, c(0.5, 0.5))}
  )
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min      lq       mean   median      uq      max neval
   m1 933.356 941.695 1011.94994 948.4305 982.429 1903.275   100
   m2  13.471  16.679   24.40241  25.6590  28.867   69.922   100
```

It seems like `spDistsN1` is a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how the performance of this code (ram usage and speed) will compare to sp code, if I run it on a large raster (~500 mb)?

Comment: Please see my update. `spDistsN1` is probably faster. However, I only compared the part of distance calculation for this particular case. It does not include the code to convert raster to other data type. It is also not clear what will happen if the size of the raster becomes larger.